# Grok conditional parsing for ELK Stack

Tags: logging, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I have this kind of log:

```
2020-09-02 14:29:22,854 [http-something] [ERROR] JavaClass(JavaLine) - [6652942]: Error message with no stack trace
2020-09-02 14:29:08,976 [http-something] [INFO] JavaClass(JavaLine) - [6791732]: Some message
2020-09-02 14:29:09,116 [http-something] [ERROR] JavaClass(JavaLine) - [6791732]: Error message with stack trace
JavaException: This is not going well
    at JavaClass
    at JavaClass
    at JavaClass
    at JavaClass
    at JavaClass
Caused by: JavaClass: This is a problem
    at JavaClass
    at JavaClass
    at JavaClass
    at JavaClass
    ... 48 more
```

and I use this filter to have a more readable log on Kibana:

```
filter {

    # INFO and ERROR
    grok {
        tag_on_failure => ["_stackTraceFailure"]
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}(\[%{DATA:thread}\])?%{SPACE}\[%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA}%{SPACE}\-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:action}" }
        overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }

    # JAVA ERROR
    if ("_stackTraceFailure" in [tags]) {
        grok { 
            tag_on_failure => ["_grokParseFailure"]
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}(\[%{DATA:thread}\])?%{SPACE}\[%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA}%{SPACE}\-%{SPACE}%{DATA:issue}(\r|\n)+(?m)%{GREEDYDATA:stack-trace}" }
            overwrite => [ "message" ]
            remove_tag => "_stackTraceFailure"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the first pattern is matching everything, putting all the stack trace (when there is one) in the **action** tag and resulting in the second pattern to never be used. I know this problem is caused by GREEDYDATA but I'm not really skilled with regex and I'm not finding a solution to do what I want.

I don't want to swap the position of the patterns because INFO and ERROR (without stack trace) are way more common so I need a way to make the first one fail in the case of a multiline log or anything that will make the first one to fail if there is some sort of stack trace. Ho can I do that starting from what I have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use conditionals before your groks. You can use a conditional to filter the entire message and use your two different `grok` filters, or you can keep your first `grok` filter as the same and use a conditional to parse only the `action` field, I would suggest the second option.

In both cases you need your conditional to filter based on something that only exists in your multiline message, in this case could be the `"at JavaClass"` string.

So you would need something like this:

```
if "at JavaClass" not in [message] {
  grok { your first grok }
} else {
    grok { your second grok }
}
```

If you want to keep your first grok and use a second one to parse only the action field, it would be something like this.

```
if "at JavaClass" in [action] {
    grok {
        tag_on_failure => ["_grokParseFailure"]
        match => { "action" => "%{DATA:issue}(\r|\n)+(?m)%{GREEDYDATA:stack-trace}" }
    }
}
```

You didn't say how you are collecting your logs, if you are using filebeat or logstash with the `multiline` coded in the input, you also could filter based on the tags, since you would have a tag named `multiline` for your logs.

Comment: I am using filebeat to collect logs with a multiline pattern (```^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}```). The multiline tag is indeed there when there are multiline logs so I guess I can also use that to let the first one fail in case that tag is true (or similar value). I will test your solution.